# Why use model.export in separate model files?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

While looking at some Stackoverflow answers for questions about splitting out model data, I see two different formats. See below:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

versus this method:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

What is the difference between using `module.exports...` versus just using `mongoose.model...`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mongoose.model` returns the `Model` it defines. Setting it as `module.exports` allows you to easily create instances of the `Model`, without retrieving it from the connection.

*a.js*

```
var User = require('./b');
var myUser = new User;
```

*b.js*

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

... note how I can directly call `new User` (after setting `User` to be `require('./b')`... this is what `module.exports` allows me to do. Note this isn't part of `mongoose` per-se, but of [Nodes module system](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).